# Problem with connecting to FTP server based on linux

Tags: linux, ftp

I cannot connect with my FTP server using any user of my domain.
The problem I receiving after correct login is

```
331 User debian OK. Password required
PASS ********
530 Login authentication failed
```

Anyone Can help with this problem?

I am using FileZilla for connection to FTP.
Password to debian user has been changed.

Comment: What FTP server application have you installed? What configuration have you used? How have you confirmed that the user "debian" and its password are correct? What reason does the FTP server log give for the authentication failure? Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/745927/edit) to add this information as if you'd included it originally